# In Classical Latin, did the prefix 'de-' in 'deputare' mean anything semantically?

Tags: etymology

> [deputy (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=deputy)     c. 1400, "one given the full power of an officer without holding the office," from Anglo-French *deputé*,
>   noun use of past participle of Middle French *députer* "appoint, assign" (14c.),
>   **[3.]** from Late Latin *deputare* "to destine, allot,"
>   **[2.]** in classical Latin "to esteem, consider, consider as," literally "to cut off, prune,"
>   **[1.]** from *de-* "away" (see [de-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=de-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *putare* "to think, count, consider," literally "to cut, prune" (see [pave](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pave&allowed_in_frame=0)).

[This answer on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12417/5306) helpfully explains the  Semantic Field of 'putare'.

4. [Wiktionary's entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deputo#Latin) states the same meanings as Etymonline above: Am I correct to interpret that the prefix *de-* added nothing semantically to the semantic shift from 1 to 2: *putare* alone already means the meanings in 2?
5. The entitled question concerns only 1 vs. 2 though; I do conjecture *de-* to add semantically to the Semantic Shift from 2 to 3, because destining or alloting something can be interpreted as cutting or pruning something, and then delegating what was cut or pruned to someone else.

Comment: You should really use a Latin dictionary for this stuff. It would answer 99% of your questions of this sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Entry on Lewis and Short's dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dde2). Here are the relevant senses, in my opinion:

> I. *the going out, departure, removal, or separating of an object from any fixed point.*
>
> > C. *In other relations, implying separation, departure from, etc.*
> >
> > > 1. *To designate the whole, from which a part is taken, or of which a part is separately regarded, etc.,* from among, out of, from
>
> II. *In composition the e becomes short before a vowel*
>
> > 2. Signif.
> >
> >    > a. *Separation, departure, removal, taking away; off, away, down, out:*
> >    >       decedo, demigro, demeto, depromo, descendo, devolvo, derivo, deflecto,
> >    >       *etc.; and trop.* dedico, denuntio; *and in a downward direction,*
> >    >       decido, decumbo, deprimo, demergo, delabor, defluo, demitto, desido,
> >    >       desideo, declivis, deculco, degredior, deicio, *etc.*

Essentially, the sense is "down from," supposedly because the deputation is made by a magistrate transferring powers "down" to the deputy.